# How do the Barycentric weights work with the Lagrange interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I am reading [this paper](https://www.nada.kth.se/%7Eolofr/Approx/BarycentricLagrange.pdf) on Barycentric Interpolation for polynomials, which is based on the Lagrange method, this is the best and shortest example that confuses me.

The standard Lagrange formula is easy to grasp:

$$ P(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n f(x_j)\; \ell_{j,n} = \sum_{j=0}^n f(x_j) \prod_{i=0,i\neq j}^n \frac{x-x_i}{x_j - x_i} $$

for given value points $f(x_i)$  and interpolation points $x_i$.

So far so clear.

Then appearently we can write
$$ \ell(x) := (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n),$$
$$\ell_j(x) :=  \ell(x) \frac{w_j}{x-x_j},   \\ w_j:=\frac{1}{\prod_{k\neq j}(x_j -x_k)}  = \frac{1}{\ell'(x_j)}.$$

The rest with the benefits of Barycentric Interpolation is clear to me but this identity really makes my head hurt, can anyone explain where the barycentric weights $w_j$ exactly come from ?

Comment: even hints would be helpful, I cannot find any proofs on this theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\ell$ by itself does not interporate your points $f(x_i)$. It is just a stepping stone in developing a later expression for the actual interpolation.

$\ell(x)$ is just the monic (i.e., leading coefficient = 1) polynomial having simple zeros at each of the interpolation points $x_i$ and no other zeros.

For fixed $j$, by removing the $(x - x_j)$ factor from $\ell$, we get another polynomial with simple zeros at all the other interpolation points, but which is non-zero for $x_j$. Call it $$L_j(x) = (x - x_0)...(x- x_{j-1})(x-x_{j+1})...(x-x_n) = \frac {\ell(x)}{x - x_j}$$

But this isn't quite useful enough. We'd like to have $\ell_j(x_j) = 1$ as well. But that is simply a matter of dividing by the right constant:
$$\ell_j(x) = \frac {L_j(x)}{L_j(x_j)}$$
You may note that $x = x_j$ is the one point where the equation $$L_j(x) = \frac {\ell(x)}{x - x_j}$$ does not hold, since the right-hand side is undefined there. However, $L_j(x_j)$ itself is defined. It is just $$L_j(x_j) = (x_j - x_0)...(x_j- x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j+1})...(x_j-x_n)$$

To make the notation a little easier, we rename $$w_j = \frac 1{L_j(x_j)}$$, giving the expression in your post. I'll leave proving that $L_j(x_j) = \ell'(x_j)$ to you.

The point of all of this is that now we have a set of polynomials with the property that $$\ell_j(x_i) = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j\\0 & i \ne j\end{cases}$$ and are the simplest such polynomials possible. And therefore we can take $$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i)\ell_i(x)$$

Comment: brilliant,thanks for taking the time. took me a bit to understand it, but I think I got it now